# How to insert scripts in database using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to insert `<script></script>` in my database, I enabled xss

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

I don't want to make it false this config variable.

With out making false, I want to insert javascript tags like this `<script></script>` in my database, any one please help me on this.

Comment: Why do you need this? this may make your site vulnerable for attack.

Answer (score 0):

What [XSS Filtering](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/security.html) does is: *if anything disallowed is encountered it is rendered safe by converting the data to character entities.*
The filtered information is saved inside your database in a safe format (using [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)), but it's all there. So what you need to do is to apply [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) when reading that particular field from database, before echoing on page.

I believe doing this is not to be recommended though, since it defies the whole purpose of xss filtering in the first place, and leaves a big security whole inside your application. Scripts should never be editable by the user.